# Button in JMenuBar cant't change data in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jmenubar

I'm writting application in java with use of swing, that uses JTable for dispaying the data from file. I created ActionListener to handle the process of adding of new data in JTable. In my app, JButton uses this ActionListener, and it works perfectly. But when i tie the same ActionListener to button in JMenuBar, something doesn't work. There is some action - apps loads data from file, but JTable doens't change at all. What can it be?
Code:

```
    //button that works. It locates in constructor
    ...
    b1.addActionListener(bl);
    ...
    //button that loads data from file, but can't update table
    ...
        public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar;
        JMenu menu, submenu;
        JMenuItem menuItem;

        // Create the menu bar.
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        // Build the first menu.
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                "The only menu in this program that has menu items");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        // a group of JMenuItems
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("import...", KeyEvent.VK_T);
        // menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T); //used constructor instead
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1,
                ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                "This doesn't really do anything");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("add file...");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("open catalog");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        menuItem.addActionListener(bl);

        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("save catalog");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        menuItem.addActionListener(b2l);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        // a group of radio button menu items
        menu.addSeparator();

        // a submenu
        menu.addSeparator();
        submenu = new JMenu("A submenu");
        submenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("An item in the submenu");
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2,
                ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        submenu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Another item");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        submenu.add(menuItem);
        menu.add(submenu);

        // Build second menu in the menu bar.
        menu = new JMenu("Edit");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                "This menu does nothing");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        return menuBar;
    }
...
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Media Cataloguer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MainInterface dm = new MainInterface();
        frame.setJMenuBar(dm.createMenuBar());
...



    ...
    //mutual ActionListener
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        //loading of array with data
                CatalogueLoader loader = new CatalogueLoader("test.ctlg");
                try {
                    Object[][] ctlgData = loader.readCtlg();

                    for (int i = 0; i < loader.size; i++) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                            table.setValueAt(ctlgData[i][j], i, j);

                        }

                    }

                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }
            }
        }
    private ButtonListener bl = new ButtonListener();
```

Comment: You need to show us a little bit of code, at least the ActionListener.

Comment: A button is a button is a button. Regardless of the button's location, it should function perfectly.

Comment: In terms of adding ActionListener it looks fine. May be you are not adding the menu item properly, but we dont see this code.

Comment: It is important to know whether the `TableModel` doesn't change or just the visual representation, the `JTable` doesn't get updated. Please use a debugger to find this out. By the way: Calling `setValueAt` on the `JTable` is both bad practise and slightly dangerous (albeit not in this case; see the corresponding Javadoc for the reason). You should change data only via its model, the `TableModel` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the same listener to the b1 and menuItem. I copied this from your code:

```
b1.addActionListener(bl);
menuItem.addActionListener(this);
```